# check duplicate mysql row

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a mysql table that contains `field_one`, `field_two`, `field_three`

I want to check if field_one contains a duplicate value (like if it was unique).

How to do that in mysql?

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

This will show you values for `field_one` that occur more than once:

```
select field_one, count(*) as Count
from MyTable
group by field_one
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This isn't very viable in large tables. OP would have to search for things have values >1. To be fair though, OP is pretty vague.

Comment: and then what should I use? echo mysql_result($q,0); ?

Comment: i like it. value field_one should be unique anyways?? but you can select id too. you would just get one of many ids, but its a start

Comment: @Matthew 0.365sec for 650k row table (running on a good server)

Answer (score 1):

```
select field_one from tblName where field_one like %'@field_one'%
```

or

```
select field_one from tblName where field_one = @filed_one
```

Comment: and then what should I use? echo mysql_result($q,0); ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if all values are unique in one column, you could use this to count all unique values:

```
select Count(Distinct column) from table
```

...and compare it to the the number of all values in the column:

```
select Count(column) from table
```

This might consume a lot of memory on large tables.